# Replace existing EPUB-files on Kobo with KEPUB-files

Tags: epub, calibre, kobo, file-format

I bought many different epubs over the years and transfered them to my KOBO (h2o) using Calibre.

With the latest update there is a new feature (fast scroll) which I'd love to use on my Kobo. Unfortunately it only works with the KEPUB format.
So I converted my entire library from epub to kepub (using calibre).

Is there any way I can REPLACE the existing EPUBs on my Kobo? While keeping my reading-stats and everything? Or maybe a way to (identify and) delete all (up-to-date) unread books and than transfer only those as KEPUB?